# How do I get rid of the extra 0 being displayed on hours when i format timestamp to NSDate string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:taskStartDate];
```

Right now its outputting times like : 01:00PM instead of 1:00PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a 2-digit hour, don't format with `hh`. Use `h`.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
```